# How to access the parent controller from the child routes in Ember JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a main route named **list**.

```
//items/list/route.js
setupController(controller, items) { 
    let vegItems = Ember.A([]);
    let nonVegItems = Ember.A([]);
    items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.get('category') === "veg") {
            vegItems.pushObject(item);
        }

        if (item.get('category') === "non_veg") {
            nonVegItems.pushObject(item);
        }
    })

    controller.set('vegItems', vegItems)
    controller.set('nonVegItems', nonVegItems);
}
```

Now inside the list route, I have the routes named **veg** and **non-veg**. i.e list/veg and list/non-veg. How can I access the controller variables of parent route, i.e **vegItems** and **nonVegItems** from list/route.js to the child route to load the data in list/veg/template.hbs and list/non-veg/template.hbs?

Comment: Why is this `setupController` even necessary?

Comment: Well @locks I infact wanted to create the variables that I needed to access inside that route. So I thought setting up controller variables is the way.

Comment: Hm, I see. Sending them through the `model()` hook is usually less error-prone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this.controllerFor('list')` - Returns the controller of the current route, or a parent (or any ancestor) route in a route hierarchy. You can get all the properties through `get` method.

`this.modelFor('list')` - Returns the resolved model of a parent (or any ancestor) route in a route hierarchy.

`list:Ember.inject.controller()` - Creates a property that lazily looks up another controller in the container. You can inject it only in the controller.

Reference:

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=controllerFor

https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=modelFor

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/namespaces/Ember.inject/methods/controller?anchor=controller